# Does postgres use index when using coalesce?

Tags: postgresql

When joining tables, if one of the tables has an index on a column (say column 'col_1'), does postgres use the index on col_1 when using COALESCE(col_1, '') in the join predicate, or do i have to create another index on the COALESCE(col_1, '').

I have tried 'explain analyze' on both queries where i use col_1 and COALESCE(col_1, '') and i saw that postgres did use the index on both queries. But am not sure if postgres always does it, cos the use of index seems to based on a lot factors.

I have tried to find some documentation on this, but was unable to find it.

So i would like to know if this will always be the case. Will it be any different if i use a CASE in the join predicate like

CASE WHEN col_1 IS NULL then '' ELSE col_1 END

will this make postgres use the index when the value isn't NULL and not when it is NULL, is that even possible or is postgres way smarter than i think and COALESCE doesn't throw it off?

basically i have an index on a column and i need to use it in a join predicate while matching NULLs. Is there a better way to do this.

**UPDATE:**

Here are the details, i have changed the table names and removed some irrelevant column names for security reasons.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab_1
(
    rid serial NOT NULL,
    ... integer,
    ... character varying(128),
    ... character varying,
    ... jsonb,
    ... bit(128) DEFAULT ''::bit(128),
    ... integer DEFAULT 0,
    ... integer DEFAULT 0,
    ... timestamp without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    ... timestamp without time zone,
    ... jsonb,
    id integer
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS tab_1_id_idx ON tab_1 (id);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab_2
(
    rid serial NOT NULL,
    ... integer,
    ... varchar (128),
    ... varchar,
    ... jsonb,
    ... integer,
    ... integer,
    ... integer,
    ... bit(128) DEFAULT ''::bit(128),
    ... integer DEFAULT 0,
    ... integer DEFAULT 0,
    ... timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    ... timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    ... jsonb,
    ... integer DEFAULT 1,
    ... timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    ... timestamp
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS tab_2_rid_idx ON tab_2 (rid);
```

Query plans:

explain analyze select 1 from tab_1 as a left join tab_2 as b on a.id = b.rid;

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=22.07..130.26 rows=1537 width=4) (actual time=0.095..0.477 rows=1537 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (a.id = b.rid)
   ->  Index Only Scan using tab_1_id_idx on tab_1 a  (cost=0.28..87.33 rows=1537 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.192 rows=1537 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
   ->  Hash  (cost=19.13..19.13 rows=213 width=4) (actual time=0.074..0.074 rows=192 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 15kB
         ->  Seq Scan on tab_2 b  (cost=0.00..19.13 rows=213 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.048 rows=192 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.208 ms
 Execution Time: 0.550 ms
```

explain analyze select 1 from tab_1 as a left join tab_2 as b on COALESCE(a.id, 0) = b.rid;

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=22.07..130.26 rows=1537 width=4) (actual time=0.110..0.513 rows=1537 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (COALESCE(a.id, 0) = b.rid)
   ->  Index Only Scan using tab_1_id_idx on tab_1 a  (cost=0.28..87.33 rows=1537 width=4) (actual time=0.023..0.209 rows=1537 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
   ->  Hash  (cost=19.13..19.13 rows=213 width=4) (actual time=0.081..0.081 rows=192 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 15kB
         ->  Seq Scan on tab_2 b  (cost=0.00..19.13 rows=213 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.054 rows=192 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.185 ms
 Execution Time: 0.587 ms
```

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) and you will know

Comment: i did use 'explain analyze' and the index was used in case of coalesce (as i mentioned in the question). But i tried it on pretty small tables around 5k entries and i have seen people indexing on the coalesce, so was not sure whether i should always expect the index to be used.

Comment: With COALESCE you are simply replacing NULLs with some other value - the index will be used but only if the replacement value is a constant.

Comment: Unless you have an index defined on the `coalesce(...)` expression, the index will *not* be used. At least I don't believe it without seeing the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: thanks @IVOGELOV, that is the kind of info i wanted.

Comment: Please show your exact case: `CREATE TABLE ...; CREATE INDEX ... ; EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...`. There seems to be a **misunderstanding**.

Comment: will update the question with the details in an hour.

Comment: hey, guys. i know been some time. but if anybody is still interested, can you give some clarity now.